# Click event not fired until 2nd click in User Control

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, user-controls, master-pages

So here is the scenario... I have an ASP.NET 4.0 website that contains a MasterPage with a usercontrol on it.  The usercontrol has a button on it with a click event wired up.  The webform that uses this MasterPage is assigned this MasterPage dynamically in the page base OnPreInit.  The webform is using the proper master page but when the button in the user control is clicked it doesn't fire until the second click.  This definitely appears to be because the masterpage is assigned dynamically but I don't know how to fix.

Comment: To clarify, does a postback occur on the first click, just the event doesn't fire?  Or does a postback not even occur?

Comment: Postback does occur. I can actually see the Page_Load event in the usercontrol fire on page entry and both clicks.

Comment: Yes.  Also I have confirmed that the button event fires normally if the webform's masterpage isnt dynamically set.  Unfortunately I need it to be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I was setting the MasterPage dynamically in the pagebase but only if not a postback.  Once I removed the postback check for the masterpage it worked as expected.

Comment: Make sure you are setting it before the Load event, too.